# Where to unregister localbroadcast receiver in order to listen even when activity is in background/foreground

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

I have an activity which listens for broadcasts and I want to catch the `broadcasts` even when my activity is in `foreground/background` or is in `onpaused` state. Now I thought about unregistering my receiver in `onstop()` method but there is a problem here which is, suppose my user pressed home button now due to which my `onstop` gets invoked because of which my register will get unregistered due to which now my activity is not able to listen for broadcasts till the moment user navigates back to my app. Now in order to overcome this problem, i thought about unregistering my listener in `ondestroy` method but there is still a problem which is as stated in Android docs, we should not do anything in `ondestroy` as because there is no surety it will get invoked every time. Now to solve this problem I thought about using `onbackpressed()` button of my activity because even when user clicks on home button my receiver will remain there and when user click on **back button** that means activity is going to be destroyed so I can simply `unregister` my receiver here.

Now I have two doubts here

**First one**- When the user taps on the home button and swipe my app from recent apps(kills my app) now do I manually have to unregister my receiver or as app is killed so I don't have to worry about that case.

**Second case**- Suppose due to application memory usage android decides to kill my activity/app, now when android will kill my activity/app as i have my unregister written in onbackpressed so do i have to unregister my receiver anywhere in my code or there won't be any problem. ALso i have seen in logs that doing that invoke `ondestroy` but as it is stated in docs so that;s why i am not using it to unregister my receiver.

Can anyone tell me have I covered all of the cases or there are still some cases left for which my solution will not work.

Also, can some one please tell me is there any other approach you guys use instead of using `onbackpressed` to solve this problem ?? If yes then please tell me.

Edit According to Android docs [activity-lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

> It is also important that you use onStop() to release resources that
>   might leak memory, because it is possible for the system to kill the
>   process hosting your activity without calling the activity's final
>   onDestroy() callback.

Also in these SO posts [android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361719/android-activity-ondestroy-is-not-always-called-and-if-called-only-part-of-the) and [is-ondestroy-not-always-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608948/is-ondestroy-not-always-called) it is stated to not use ondestroy()

**EDIT**- My use case is when I get a push notification through FCM i want to send a broadcast to my activity and then the new element will be added in my list.

Comment: where did you get the info that **ondestroy might not be invoked every time** ? In https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#ondestroy i donot see that info

Comment: @k3b please see my updated post I have added android doc URL.

Comment: Did try you to register the broadcast in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: @NicoT. It is a localbroadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

1. The cleanst way is to have a global broadcast receiver that listens all the time.
2. The most common use of a local broadcast receiver is to register/listen only while the app is visible between `onStart()` and `onStop()` to update the gui
3. you can also have a service with a local broadcast receiver if you have to do more ongoing processing.
4. If you really must run the local broadcast receiver even if the activity has stopped (= is in background) but is not destoryed yet you have to register/listen between `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`

I assume you have a good reason why you need (4).

As you mentioned there are cases when `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`are not called

[SDK Activity.html#onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) tells

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it.

You are searching for a place in the lifeceycle that is garanteed to be called to unregister the listener but i am afraid there is none.

I assume that `"kill the activity's hosting"` is either

- there is an uncaught exception in the activity or
- android is killing the complete app, including its broadcastreceivers for memory reasons.

Comment: So according to you in the second case, I don't have to do anything as Android is itself killing all memory(Localbroadcastreceiver also).

Comment: Also as the global broadcast is used to communicate with system wide apps(other apps also), that's why I don't want to use it as I can work with localbroadcastreceivers only.

Comment: are you there ??