# What can we do to ensure that onDestroy() gets called?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-ondestroy

I have a line of code that I should call after my activity is destroyed, so I override `onDestroy()` method and I call it inside. Like this:

```
   @override
   public void onDestroy(){

     //my code here

     super.onDestroy()  

   }
```

Now I noticed that the this line of code is not always executed when my activity finishes.

I read about this and some said don't depend on `onDestroy()` method to call something.

My question is I need to call the code from `onDestroy()` and I want it to always work. Any thoughts on this? And why `onDestroy()` is found in the first place if we cant depend on it to execute?

Comment: check this links why onDestroy is not always called. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608948/is-ondestroy-not-always-called

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to depend on `onDestroy()` for your cleanup works. It is better to perform these operation in `onPause()` or `onStop()`. These are the callback methods which the system calls whenever your activity goes out of view.

Comment: But I have to call the code only when my activity is finished. Not when it is out of view.

Comment: This will serve your purpose, whatever is it that you are trying to clear in onDestroy, you can reinitialise it in onResume(). There is no way to explicitly call onDestroy. It is a system call and android does it whenever it needs to clear some memory.

Comment: I initialize a listener in onCreate and remove it in onDestroy. I have to do it this way.

Comment: I cant reinitialize.

Comment: listeners are ideally initialised in onResume and cleared it in onPause. I dont understand why you can't do that.

Comment: I call a method from onCreate, now when I resume my activity I dont want this method to be called so I cant put the method in onStart() or in onResume().

Comment: And I must clean in onDestroy().

Comment: I think I understood what you are trying to do. If I understand correctly, the correct way to do it is use a flag. Set that flag to true once your method in onResume is called.Put a check in onResume to see the status of the flag before calling your listener. Initialise that flag in onCreate and clear it in onDestroy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168015/discussion-between-ezio-and-svi-data).

Answer (score 1):

> Now I noticed that the this line of code is not always executed when my activity finishes.

Either:

- `onDestroy()` is called, or
- You crashed with an unhandled exception, or
- Your process was terminated (e.g., user revoked a runtime permission from Settings, Android needed RAM in a hurry)

> I read about this and some said don't depend on onDestroy() method to call something.

Correct. `onDestroy()` is for cleanup of things assuming that your app is continuing to run normally. However, if your app is no longer running normally (you crashed) or your app is gone (process terminated), `onDestroy()` is not relevant.

> I need to call the code from onDestroy() and I want it to always work. Any thoughts on this?

You will need to reconsider those two requirements, as they cannot both be true. Either initialize in `onStart()` and clean up in `onStop()`, or live with the fact that your cleanup code may not be called. Even the `onStop()` scenario is not completely guaranteed — in a multi-window environment, the user could revoke a runtime permission in Settings while your app is still visible — but we're getting into fairly unlikely scenarios.

Comment: So onDestroy() is called only when I finish my activity in a clean way. And it won't be called when the activity finishes it self due to a crash.

Comment: So if onDestroy is not guaranteed then why does it exist any way.

Comment: @svi.data: Mostly, it is there to clean up stuff that might result in memory leaks (e.g., dangling threads). If your process is being terminated, the memory goes away and so there are no more leaks to consider. If your app crashed, you have bigger problems than a memory leak. And in all other cases, `onDestroy()` gets called.

Comment: @CommonsWare, re *"And in all other cases [everywhere], `onDestroy()` gets called"* ??? Didn't the documentation explicitly said No to that.

Comment: @Pacerier: If you have a link that disagrees with the three bullets at the top of my answer, I'd love to see it!

Comment: @CommonsWare, Separately, re *"we're getting into fairly unlikely scenarios"*; You're aware that onDestroy is (almost) **never** called when the user clears the activity off the back stack right? as tested on my system here.

Comment: @Pacerier: "when the user clears the activity off the back stack right?" -- if you mean the user presses BACK, `onDestroy()` is always called unless you are taking steps to prevent the activity from honoring it (e.g., override `onBackPressed()`. If you mean swipe the app off the overview screen, your mileage may vary depending on device manufacturer and OS version.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yea point being it's very common for onDestroy not to be called too.

Comment: @Pacerier: Everything that you have described so far fits the three bullets at the top of my answer. Swiping the app off the overview screen, for example, if it does not trigger `onDestroy()`, is because the process was simply terminated immediately. If you override `onBackPressed()` and suppress the default `finish()` behavior, `onDestroy()` will not be called at that point in time, but it might at a later point (e.g., app code itself calls `finish()`).

Comment: @CommonsWare, yep the bullets cover all bases... Your point is that missing `onDestroy` is exceptional. My point is I never count on `(Application)getApplicationContext()` to ever work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee `onDestroy` it will ever be called, but i had rely on  `onPause` to check if the `Activity` is finishing by calling `if( isFinishing() ) // activity is about to finish` yet this might not work properly.

I had rethink of my logic to not rely `onDestroy` at all.

```
boolean isFinishing ()
```

> Check to see whether this activity is in the process of finishing,
>   either because you called finish() on it or someone else has requested
>   that it finished. This is often used in onPause() to determine whether
>   the activity is simply pausing or completely finishing.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29

Answer (score 0):

These are the system calls for the method they will crash when they are called explicitly by the programmer...

Comment: Your answer neither answers the question nor make any sense. Please add a more detailed answer and if required add code too.