# How to know if my activity is destroyed in service?

Tags: java, android, service

What i'm trying to achieve is that when i close my app from recents i can still control my apps through my notification.

All works well but when i click the close button in my notification when my application is still running i get alot of NPE's.

**Code that gets executed when close button in notification is clicked:**

```
mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            Main.unbindService(getApplicationContext());
            stopSelf();
            Log.d(TAG,"stop!");
}
```

Now when i close my application and then destroy my **Service** through the notification all works perfectly.

So my question is how i can determine when my application is still running ( visible for the user or in the background(recent apps) and when it gets destroyed and only the notification is present?

So then i can create if statements to only call `stopSelf();` when the app is destroyed and don't call it when my application is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` method might be of use to you. You could put something like this in your application's `onCreate()` method:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        int activityCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            activityCount++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            activityCount--;
        }
    });
```

and use it to keep track of whether any of your activities are still running.

**EDIT**: Ok, if you want to avoid the situation where a finished activity keeps hanging for some time before the `onDestroyed()` method is called, you can use a bit more advanced approach, where you check whether the activity is finishing in the `onActivityPaused` and `onActivityStopped`. So you make a class like this:

```
private class ActivityWatcher implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    //a set of currently running activities
    private Set<Activity> activities = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activities.add(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        if (activity.isFinishing()) {
            activities.remove(activity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        if (activity.isFinishing()) {
            activities.remove(activity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        activities.remove(activity);
    }

    public boolean isAnyActivityRunning() {
        return !activities.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

and then in your application class you create an instance and register it as activity lifecycle callback:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ActivityWatcher activityWatcher = new ActivityWatcher();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activityWatcher);
    }

    public boolean isAppAlive() {
        return activityWatcher.isAnyActivityRunning();
    }
}
```

Should work.

Comment: OnDestroy does not always get called, so that's not a safe way to check if my activity is still running.

Comment: If your activity is not destroyed, then it's still running, no? Anyway, if you're concerned that it might take a long time before a finished activity is actually destroyed, you could make a check in the `onActivityPaused` whether the activity is finishing (call `activity.isFinishing()`) and handle it the same as activity being destroyed. Of course in that case you couldn't use a simple counter because you could decrement it twice for a single activity. Instead you would need to keep track of _which_ activity is finishing and/or being destroyed.

Comment: But it seems that there can be a situation where onDestroy doesn't get called. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608985

Comment: And if that happens my app would crash which would give a bad user experience.

Comment: Yeah, the onDestroy won't be called if the OS kills your whole process. But if that happens, you service will be called as well so the whole point is moot, no?

Comment: my onDestroy doesn't get called when i remove the app from my recent apps for some reason but sometimes it does gets called?